r Error when I try to run the browser function in RStudio
I recently updated from RStudio 2021 version to 2023.12.1:

RStudio 2023.12.1+402 "Ocean Storm" Release (4da58325ffcff29d157d9264087d4b1ab27f7204, 2024-01-28) for windows
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio/2023.12.1+402 Chrome/116.0.5845.190 Electron/26.2.4 Safari/537.36

I am running R 4.4.0.
When I try to run the browser() function now, I get an infinitely repeating error:
Warning: type 29 is unimplemented in 'type2char' Error: INTEGER() can only be applied to a 'integer', not a 'unknown type #29' 

The following is a minimal R script that produces this error:
a <- function(vec) {
    browser()
    vec <- 4
}
a()

This error is very frustrating because I use the browser() function very frequently and currently I can't use it at all.
My computer is running Windows 10 Enterprise 22H2.
It is not easy for me to update RStudio because it's a corporate computer so I would have to get IT services to update RStudio, so I need to know whether updating RStudio will fix this problem?

Your code works on RStudio 2024.04.1 with R 4.4.0. When I had IT issues at a previous workplace, I just installed both on a USB device and avoided IT delays that way. From Posit: "you simply need to copy the RStudio directory (normally located in Program Files) onto your USB device. To open RStudio from this device, run rstudio.exe located in the bin folder." Or given that you want the most up-to-date version, search for a portable version and do a fresh install straight to a USB device.

If you can't wait for your IT dept. to update RStudio for you, you might find this link useful.

thanks for the confirmation that later versions run without the error. And thanks for the info about portable RStudio
